# Tables Azure SQL database not 'recognized' by Altova DatabaseSpy

Tags: sql-server, azure, altova

I'm experimenting with Altova DatabaseSpy to manage an Azure SQL Database. I've made connection and can manipulate the database through the sql editor.

The tables and views however are not showing in the 'Online Browser' and much of the functionality as the 'import function' and the 'design function' is not working. It seems like the tables are not 'recognized' in some way.

Anyone experience with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about SSMS? If you connect using the *same* credentials, then it's a bug in DatabaseSpy. If you can't see the tables even in SSMS, then you are connecting with an account that only has permissions to connect to the database, not read the schema or tables.

Comment: They are visible in SSMS with the same credentials You're probarly right and it's a bug. Thnx.